# Work done in uniform circular motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, work

I received this lesson earlier, and I’m struggling to understand how this works. In the image below, my physics teacher shows that there is some sort of work done over one revolution of a mass in a circle.  From my previous knowledge, it seems like there should be 0 work done. Why is it that there is in this example? [image: The proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in the $cos(\theta) = 0$. This is supposed to be the angle between the force (centrifugal force in this case) and the direction of the displacement.

They are perpendicular, so it should be $cos(\theta) = cos(90º) = 0$.

So your reasoning was correct in the first place :)